# Translate series of icons in images into text

Tags: image, object, detection

I have hundreds of images I want to pull information out of. Each image contains a series (4 groups, aligned horizontally) of little icons that I want to translate into a text file. The program will know how to translate these icons into text via a simple definition I set up before, telling it what each icon means. The icons in the source images that I want to scan will always have the same perspective, size, coloring. So it should be a simple matching solution without involving some kind of AI.

Here are some pictures to visualize what I mean:

[Example of image I want to scan and translate into text via a definition of what each icon means](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjCee.png)

[Definition of what each icon means](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjs89.png)

So after setting up the definition in the program and having it scan the example image, the output should be something like this:
Scopesmith Necromancer | Greyhound Necromancer Beastface | Fanning Determination Ghoul Bloodless | Fanning Levering Poacher Greyhound

Every google search for how to approach this leads me to AI, but I'm thinking there should be a less complex solution since it's simple image matching by a predefined set of rules. If someone could point me towards a tool for this problem that's already existing or towards what I should be searching for on google, it would help me out a lot. I have no experience in image processing but some experience in coding, so if I know how to describe the problem to a search engine I think I can manage.

Comment: Try *"Template Matching"* see https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Comment: Are the positions (in the long horizontal bar) where the images could occur known and fixed. I understand there could be gaps and so on, but could the first image from the left be 10 pixels further left or right, or do they always occur as fixed positions if they occur at all? What I am getting at, is if it is possible to chop up the long horizontal bar into pieces at known, fixed locations and test each piece against each icon?

Comment: You've gone very quiet. Is this question abandoned?